# If I need to change coding style, should I ask for a standard to follow?

Tags: software-industry, standards

I got my first programming job.

It started well but now I got a message that I should write clearer code. I think my code is clear enough.

Is it worth of asking if the boss has some coding standards on his mind of should I just change the way of coding gradually while he finds something that is not clear enough?

He showed me another way to write the code and I can say that styles are approximately equally easy to read, it is a matter of taste which is clearer. I work in my home and boss is from another city so we see each other quite seldom.

Comment: Keep an archive (version) of the old code then add your changes, review both codes to your manager that shows what you did to improve it and let him decide what direction he wants. This is the most common way of handling this.

Comment: Since he showed you another way to code, I'd say he already showed you the standard he wants.  Just roll with it.

Comment: "it is a matter of taste which is clearer" - Use the one that fits the taste of your boss and/or seniors.

Comment: Are you talking about a coding style such as K&R vs Gnu vs Linux Kernel?

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter if _you_ think your code is clear enough; the whole team is supposed to be able to read and understand it. Even if you are considerably better than they are, you might have to tone it down a notch just because you won't be maintaining the project alone.

Comment: Here's the secret you need to know:  Coding so the computer operates correctly is the *bare minimum* you have to do.  Quality code is something that the programmer who comes behind you three years from now can read and understand not only the function, but the intent and hopefully the context when they have to make changes.

Comment: "I got a message that I should write clearer code" - ask the message giver to define "clearer" - why are you asking us?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's software specific.

Answer (score 27):

> Is it worth of asking if the boss has some coding standards on his
>   mind of should I just change the way of coding gradually while he
>   finds something that is not clear enough?

When someone says something to you and you don't understand it, the only way you'll gain clarity is by asking questions. That is as true on the job as it is in life.

It doesn't make sense for you to randomly keep changing your coding style in hopes of honing in on what your boss wants.

Schedule a meeting with your boss (preferably in person, but via screen sharing if necessary). Mention that you don't really understand what he means by writing clearer code. Provide samples of your code and ask how you could make it clearer. Ask if there is a standard (written or otherwise). Ask if there is code you can read which demonstrates that standard particularly well.

Then you will know.

> I got a message that I should write clearer code. I think my code is
>   clear enough.
>
> He showed me another way to write the code and I can say that styles
>   are approximately equally easy to read, it is a matter of taste which
>   is clearer.

If you approach this with the attitude that your code is obviously clear enough and your boss shouldn't suggest that your code needs to be clearer, then you'll never make any progress. You may also harm your career.

This is your first programming job. Try to take it on faith that you might have a few things to learn - doing that will serve you well. I worked for 45 years and learned new things all the time.

Comment: The boss may have his own prefer style and want to be applied everywhere. Kind of a standard without it being written, so it may even be the opportunity to write it down.

Comment: Was about to answer "Yes", but this is even better. As it states why "yes" is so important in this situation.

Comment: Good answer, the only thing I'd add is that if he's bugfixing or modifying code written by others, he should try to maintain the same style of his predecessors

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sure, I'm assuming that previous code is correct. My point is that when in doubt and there are no specific guidelines, it's always better to follow already established styles.

Comment: @Walfrat: "Clearer code" and "coding standard" or "coding style" are largely unrelated. Asking for a coding standard when asked for "clearer code" just shows someone doesn't understand "clearer code".

Comment: Since we don't have the OP's code and his boss's one, I am assuming the same than BgrWorker : OP's code was off the same quality than his boss since that's what OP said.

Comment: OP is a beginner. Boss seems to be an experienced developer. OP seems to be at the wrong end of the Dunning-Kruger curve where people don't even realise their incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

Now there are several things to "clearer code"

first is style that can be described in a style-guide. Such are found on the web for many flours and languages and it is advisable a team subscribes to one and the same style even if most are "*approximately equally easy to read, and a matter of taste*"
example: [Delphi syle guide](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280)

You should ask your boss if he has something like this. If not, get one off the internet to see which points are usually covered. Find how this is handled in your organisation by looking at other code and/or asking your boss. You could even write it down for future use and onboarding of new programmers.

Second, the way you structure you logic could be construed as clear or unclear coding. Almost anyone can improve in this field so I suggest picking up some good books like Martin Fowlers: Refactoring or Robert C. Martins: Clean code.

Last when and how you comment, name variable and methods also contributes to clarity.

You should find out exactly which of these points set off your boss and work on that especially. Nonetheless professional try to master all of them.

Comment: "Style that can be described in a style-guide" has nothing, nothing whatsoever to do with clearer code.

Comment: @gnasher729: Interesting Opinion. I beg to differ, especially regarding naming conventions. But I can see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You are in your very first job. There are things that you don't know, that will (hopefully) become clear as you gain experience. I'm assuming that right now, your boss is the better software developer.

Code is "clear" if I can easily find out what it is supposed to do, and then easily can find out that it indeed does what it is supposed to do. That's it. With "clear" code, there is an obvious goal, and every line of code goes directly into the direction of achieving that goal. Clear code is as simple as it can be, because all difficulty comes from the problem, and not from difficulties coming from the code.

I sometimes see code examples on stackoverflow.com where I think "What is this developer thinking?". Where they achieve their goal, but taking the weirdest, most obscure, most complicated paths getting there. That is unclear code.

It takes time to develop the ability to create clear code. It has absolutely nothing to do with coding standards, so asking for coding standards only shows that you don't know what "clear code" means. And writing clear code is not something you just can do as ordered. It's something you learn. It's like telling a fiction writer "write more interesting stories". It has nothing to do with style.

As to your comment "I think my code is clear enough". It isn't. The problem is, if you think it is, it might stop you from improving.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, we are the worst person for determining whether our code is clear.  The code came from our head, so it's no surprise that it makes sense in our head.  However, code also has to make sense to other people as well.  Sometimes two styles can look equally clear to us, while one is far more clear to others.

Early in your career, I recommend slavishly following code standards provided by your boss (aka. the one who signs your paychecks).  They are the ones paying for the code, so they get to say what it looks like.  As your skill matures, you will have the opportunity to see more coding styles, and develop a more robust model of what makes code "clear" not only to yourself, but to others.  Then you will have a bit more freedom to challenge the status quo.

There is also value in conformance.  The hardest style of code to read is code which is written in multiple competing styles.  If you get used to one style, you can start to read into the mind of the developers by how they leverage that style.  It's harder to do that if each developer has their own coding style.

Answer (score -1):

There is a gap you need to overcome before you ask. You compared your code to what he gave you and didn't detect the deltas. To your boss there must be clear differences. Study the coding style of other code in the repo and patterns may emerge. You will also become more familiar with the code base at the same time.

Comment: The OP did detect delta's, they just didn't feel they were significant enough to warrant making changes.

Comment: @Cronax, My wording was poor with code and delta in the same sentence. I meant the deltas in his perceptions of "significant", not the code differences.